# Connecting Access ADO to SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql, ms-access, connection, ado

I am trying to create a connection to my SQL Server via Access. I do not want to link tables as some of the tables in the DB are very large. I will be executing queries in Access that will pull out the information from SQL server.

```
Sub CreateConnection()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "Server=MBLWINDOWS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AdventureWorks2012; UserId=myUsername;Password=myPassword"

Debug.Print cnn.ConnectionString

cnn.Close

End Sub
```

The username and password to access the SQL server is the users windows login and password

How can i incorporate this in my connection string?

Comment: *"I do not want to link tables as some of the tables in the DB are very large."* It sounds like you don't really understand how linked tables work.

Comment: Just as a quick follow up, the fact of having a linked table with 1 million rows does NOT cause access to pull down all records. In fact you can launch a form (or report) bound to that linked tables and using a where clause such as Where Customer id = 134 will ONLY pull down the 1 record into that form or report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that works

```
Sub CreateConnection()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection


With cnn
.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MBLWINDOWS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=SSPI"
.Open


End With

If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then

MsgBox "Connection established"

End If

cnn.Close


Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the user's Windows credentials to connect to SQL Server, just use the `Integrated Security` setting in the connection string:

```
Server=MBLWINDOWS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

and that's all there is.